# Flutter+Android Studio: Can't resolve Java symbols from external libraries

Tags: java, android, flutter

I'm trying to build a Flutter app that also runs custom Java code, so that I can execute code in the background, set alarms etc. As such, I'd like to access Firebase from Java.

I've created a new Flutter project in Android Studio and added Firebase as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase) (manually).

It compiles and runs fine on the device, but it seems that the dependency .jars from Gradle are not picked up in Android Studio, and as a result my Java source files show a lot of errors - source being ["cannot resolve symbol 'google'"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBkxI.png) in the import statements.

Is there anything special that I need to do in order to have Android Studio pick up external Java dependencies from Gradle in Flutter application projects? I'm running Android Studio 3.0 Beta 7.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and would love to find the solution. I tried directly downloading the .aar file and using this guide but it did not work either.

https://github.com/yushulx/flutter-android-aar

Edit: I found an open issue on the topic [which can be found here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/966). Clearly you have found it, but in case anyone else is looking for more information about this.

Edit 2: [Here is a workaround.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613594/flutter-intellij-plugin-java-language-support)

Comment: Do you know if there is any update that should address this? I am currently facing the same issue: opening the android portion of my flutter project shows no errors, but the android folder in my flutter project shows errors (but compiles)